# PDF created with iText looks different on different systems

Tags: java, email, pdf, download, itext

I have succeeded in generating PDF using the iText library, but I am experiencing a strange problem. When I download the PDF file on my own system, it looks OK; I would describe it as regular and correct. However, when I send the PDF file to my friends by email, it has a different layout, which I would describe as irregular. When I scan the PDF on the internet (without downloading), it also looks irregular. So I wonder: did I do anything wrong, and if so, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: How is it irregular? We cannot help you unless you provide more details.

Comment: First guess: you are not embedding any fonts. PDF stands for *Portable* Document Format, which means that it doesn't matter where (or on which OS) you view a PDF; it should always look the same. The main exception is when using unembedded fonts. Create your PDF as a PDF/A file to solve this problem. Second guess: your friends use a broken PDF viewer; many of the "PDF scanners" found online don't really work. Third guess: you're using an obsolete version of iText.

Comment: *"did I do anything wrong"* - most likely. *"and if so, how can I fix this problem?"* - You should start by providing some information on what you actually have done, i.e. adding the pivotal code to the question and sharing a sample result PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are creating a PDF with special characters. Let's say that you are mixing English and Chinese text using a specific font that you found on *your* system.

Suppose that you don't embed a subset of this font. This means that the PDF contains Unicode values of the special characters you have used in your document, *but the PDF doesn't know how to display the corresponding glyphs*.

Now when you open this PDF on your own machine, it will look perfect. Why? Because you have the PDF with the Unicode values *and* you have the font that is needed *on your own system*.

However, when your friends receive the document, and open the PDF, they have the Unicode characters, but **not the font**. Their PDF viewer will use a different font than the one you had in mind. As a result, the content may look different (the word I'd use is *jumbled*). The same is true when you put the PDF on some online storage and then look at the PDF in a browser: if that online storage serves the PDF as an image, the text in that image will look jumbled because the online service doesn't have access to the font you have on your system.

How to fix this problem? **Embed (a subset of) the font!**

I don't know which version of iText you are using and you didn't share any code, but when you create a `BaseFont` in iText 5 or a `FontProgram`/`PdfFont` in iText 7, you can use a parameter to indicate whether the font should be embedded in the document.

Don't worry that iText will embed the *full* font in case you have a huge Chinese font. In that case, iText will subset the font, and only add the glyphs that are used in the document.